# Event Scheduler to multiple MySQL databases

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to figure out if its possible to have EVENT SCHEDULER take data from one database and update it to another. I checked mysql site and google but there isn't any info on this. I know how to create events and understand the process. I am thinking of using php and mysql but not sure if that would work.

**Why I need this:**

Database A - gets a lot of traffic
Database B - gets little traffic

I want to run certain queries (counts mostly) to run once a day from Database A. Then store the results inside Database B. This way when some loads a page that has to do a count, it wont run the count query but instead just SELECT * FROM database B. Making it load faster.

Comment: I assume you mean from one database host to another database host?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: yes they are two different hosts. please see my update as to the use.

Comment: Do you have two different database servers or one database server with two databases?

Comment: I have two different databases. One is actually a localhost and another is hosted outside.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to do is to replicate your databases!

For example you can specify Database 'A' as your publisher and Database 'B' as your subscriber. There are lot of articles on the internet regarding replicating MySQL databases. Google and find out. Anyway have a look at this question over here [MySQL Event Scheduler on a specific time everyday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3070277/1187031). This might give you an idea on what to achieve.

Comment: Take a look at these too.... Might help you if you want to replicate databases [MySQL database replication](http://stackoverflow.com/q/793196/1187031) and [MySQL reference Manual replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html)